# VBA ActiveX controls grow in size over Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: excel, vba, activex, remote-desktop

We have an Excel workbook with a number of ActiveX controls, running in Excel 2003 on Windows XP.  When connecting using Remote Desktop, the ActiveX controls change font, sometimes font size, and sometimes orientation (in the case of a spinner control).  This happens on first connection and also as the workbook is used - some of the controls then enlarge in size, often overlapping other controls and part of the workbook.

I read somewhere this may be caused by improper connection management (not closing them) leading to increasing memory usage; are there other reasons why the display is so different over Remote Desktop and are there workarounds?  (the properties of each control usually remain the same, so force-resizing them doesn't always have an effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [read](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/slowresp.htm) this. Hope it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: @RJ1516: I read through that and didn't find any particular reference to the problem Alistair is talking about. Do you have a particular location on that page he should look at?

Comment: @ToddMain OP was/is supposed to copy/paraphrase the relevant text here in case the original link is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976938/en-us